# Workbox not caching start_url on inital load

Tags: caching, service-worker, workbox

I've been using Google's [workbox library](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/workbox) for a little while now, on a very basic level. Most of it works great, but for some reason the `start_url` in my `manifest.json` isn't being cached on initial page load (reported by Lighthouse, confirmed in dev tools). If you browse around a bit, or soft-refresh the page a few times, it does seem to cache, it just doesn't do it initially.

I assume I'm doing something wrong, but it's not clear to me what that is. Demo URL and source code below.

- https://framework.jacob.rocks/
- https://framework.jacob.rocks/manifest.json

```js
import { skipWaiting, clientsClaim } from "workbox-core";
import { ExpirationPlugin } from "workbox-expiration";
import { precacheAndRoute } from "workbox-precaching";
import { setCatchHandler, registerRoute } from "workbox-routing";
import { CacheFirst, NetworkFirst } from "workbox-strategies";

skipWaiting();
clientsClaim();

/**
 * Cache WordPress content
 */
registerRoute(
    ({ url }) => {
        return (url.pathname && !url.pathname.match(/^\/(wp-admin|wp-content|wp-includes|wp-json|wp-login)/) && url.pathname.match(/\/$/));
    },
    new NetworkFirst({
        cacheName: "new_site-content-cache",
        plugins: [
            new ExpirationPlugin({
                maxAgeSeconds: 7 * 24 * 60 * 60,
            }),
        ],
    })
);

/**
 * Cache CSS files
 */
registerRoute(
    ({ url }) => {
        return (url.pathname && url.pathname.match(/\.css$/) && !url.pathname.match(/wp-admin|wp-includes|wp-json/));
    },
    new CacheFirst({
        cacheName: "new_site-css-cache",
        plugins: [
            new ExpirationPlugin({
                maxAgeSeconds: 7 * 24 * 60 * 60,
            }),
        ],
    })
);

/**
 * Cache JS files
 */
registerRoute(
    ({ url }) => {
        return (url.pathname && url.pathname.match(/\.js$/) && !url.pathname.match(/wp-admin|wp-includes|wp-json/) && !url.pathname.match(/redirection/));
    },
    new CacheFirst({
        cacheName: "new_site-js-cache",
        plugins: [
            new ExpirationPlugin({
                maxAgeSeconds: 7 * 24 * 60 * 60,
            }),
        ],
    })
);

/**
 * Cache image files
 */
registerRoute(
    ({ url }) => {
        return (url.pathname && url.pathname.match(/\.gif|jpeg|jpg|png|svg|webp$/) && !url.pathname.match(/wp-admin|wp-includes|wp-json/));
    },
    new CacheFirst({
        cacheName: "new_site-image-cache",
        plugins: [
            new ExpirationPlugin({
                maxAgeSeconds: 7 * 24 * 60 * 60,
            }),
        ],
    })
);

/**
 * Cache font files
 */
registerRoute(
    ({ url }) => {
        return (url.pathname && url.pathname.match(/\.otf|ttf|woff|woff2$/) && !url.pathname.match(/wp-admin|wp-includes|wp-json/));
    },
    new CacheFirst({
        cacheName: "new_site-font-cache",
        plugins: [
            new ExpirationPlugin({
                maxAgeSeconds: 7 * 24 * 60 * 60,
            }),
        ],
    })
);

/**
 * Return "offline" page when visiting pages offline that haven't been cached
 */
setCatchHandler(() => {
    return caches.match("/offline/");
});

/**
 * Precache "offline" page
 */
precacheAndRoute([
    {
        url: "/offline/",
        revision: __VERSION__,
    },
]);
```

**UPDATE 1:** Okay, so I found [this issue](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/workbox/issues/1415) which I think is the problem. It seems that the initial response isn't cached because the service worker is installed after the request, so it has nothing to cache. I'm still not seeing a way to fix this, but will post another update if I make any progress.

**UPDATE 2:** It seems like using `skipWaiting()` and `clientsClaim()` is *supposed* to be the solution to this, but after adding those, it's still not working as expected. It's strange, Lighthouse reports "Current page responds with a 200 when offline," but also "start_url does not respond with a 200 when offlineThe start_url did respond, but not via a service worker." That doesn't make sense because it's the same page... maybe I'm doing something wrong with trying to route `/`?

**UPDATE 3:** Tried changing the last check in my first `registerRoute` to `/\/?$/`, made no difference. Also tried changing `NetworkFirst` to `CacheFirst` and that actually works fine... but I need it to be `NetworkFirst`, so that's not really a viable option to get around this issue. I also tried precaching `/`, but that again made no difference.

**UPDATE 4:** I suspect that [this "warm the runtime cache" recipe](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/guides/advanced-recipes#warm_the_runtime_cache) may be close to what I need, but I haven't been able to successfully implement... if I hard code the `start_url`, it at least caches the HTML, but misses all other files. It seems like [this method of gathering all resources](https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/pwa-wp/issues/180#issuecomment-506982638) may be useful, but `location.href` is just returning the service worker URL, and even if it weren't, I'm not sure how I'd split everything out in to their own caches like I'm currently doing.

Answer (score 1):

Just as [the method of gathering all resources](https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/pwa-wp/issues/180#issuecomment-506982638) says, the page and resources are not cached because they are loaded before the service worker was installed.

Why not use [`workbox-build`](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/modules/workbox-build) to inject **essential** precache manifest at build time? Assets will be precached at service worker install time.

Quick example, add following line into `service-worker.js`:

```js
precacheAndRoute(self.__WB_MANIFEST);
```

And run the following js script after build:

```js
const {injectManifest} = require('workbox-build');

const swSrc = 'src/sw.js';
const swDest = 'build/sw.js';
injectManifest({
  swSrc,
  swDest,
  globDirectory: 'build',
  globPatterns: ['*.@(js|css)']
}).then(({count, size}) => {
  console.log(`Generated ${swDest}, which will precache ${count} files, totaling ${size} bytes.`);
});
```

You can even set `swSrc` and `swDest` to be the same, to inject manifest in place.

I think it's not neccesary to split assets out in to different caches, but it's possible using [`getManifest`](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/modules/workbox-build#getmanifest_mode) mode, glob one type of assets at a time, and manually inject them into certain point in `service-worker.js`

Comment: This may work, but it seems to be designed using the generator rather than something I can slot in to my custom solution. Because it's used on WordPress-based websites, I don't want to pre-generate everything, I need it to be dynamic enough to pull in things as the page changes with user modifications.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and found that the expression generated by workbox wizard is faulty. So I changed it and it now pre-cahcing all the site resources on the first load.

```
globPatterns: [
        '**/*.{html, json, svg, png, gif, txt, css, js}'
    ],
```

I changed this to be like the following and it worked fine with me

```
globPatterns: [
        '**/*.js',
        '**/*.html',
        '**/*.css',
        '**/*.json',
        '**/*.svg',
        '**/*.png',
        '**/*.gif',
        '**/*.txt',
    ],
```

You can check the generated sw.js to find the different resources inserted in the actual sw.js file to know which resources were cached.